# Multiple threads for StaTaskScheduler in ViewModel

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, viewmodel, sta

ListBox contains list of files with their icons. I am trying to have 10 icons extracted at the same time but icons appear at same rate whether I have 1 of 10 as number of threads for StaTaskScheduler (TPL extensios).

```
public class FileData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
...     
private ImageSource icon = MainWindow.DefaultFileIcon;
public ImageSource Icon
{
    get
    {           
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Icon = cIcon.GetIcon(FullPath); //uses SHGetFileInfo so STA is needed
        }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, FactorySTA.MyStaIcon); 
        return icon;
    }
    set
    {
        if (icon != value)
        {
            icon = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Icon");
        }
    }
}


public static class FactorySTA
{
        public static readonly StaTaskScheduler MyStaIcon = new StaTaskScheduler(10);
}

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:FileData}"  > 
  <StackPanel...>
    <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" />
```

If this worked, I would also expect icons to appear in non-sequential order since it takes more time to get icon from an .exe file.

Comment: where do you set `icon` in the Task you start? is it `Icon = cIcon.GetIcon(FullPath);` this line and the capital Icon is just a typo?

Comment: @Dominik Not a typo. I am binding from xaml to Icon

Comment: try awaiting the task you start in get

Comment: @Dominik I was told never to use await in getters